# Select query selecting individual column values instead SUM (HAVING/GROUP BY)

Tags: sql, derby

In code snippet below you can see select query which I want to use to select drivers in chosen city with total point count greater than 7 (inclusive). It looks good to me, but there is one bug. When I run this query, only tuples from `offenses` where `d.point_count >= 7` are included in `sum(d.point_count)` . What I am doing wrong? I want to get result where all `d.point_count` are included in `sum`. Should not be `HAVING` clause filtering `GROUP BY` "result"?

```
SELECT d.name,
   d.surname,
   d.city,
   d.ID,
   SUM(o.point_count) AS point_count,
   COUNT(e.ID) AS offense_count
FROM events e
INNER JOIN drivers d ON (e.ID_driver = d.ID)
INNER JOIN offenses o ON (e.ID_offense = o.ID)
WHERE (d.city = 'Ostrava')
GROUP BY d.ID,d.name,d.surname,d.city
HAVING (SUM(o.point_count) >= 7)
```

**What is my main problem**: there are not included all offenses in result but only those, which point_count is greater than 7. I want to include all offenses but filter out those 'drivers' whose points for all their offenses is less than 7.

Query result with no having clause or where clause (name, surname, id, point count, offense count):

```
name      surname   city        x  y  z

R4UB8K    U00XM2G5F Olomouc     1  9  1
IVJZ4T9B  4BDKK4Q   Brno        2 14  2
U94Z8     19IBVY5J1 Praha       3 10  3
4WPG8     BL4FDM    Olomouc     4  6  1
AZ956DS   4H45D     Olomouc     5  6  1
HHXW1WY8Q 7S1WX1HL  Praha       6  9  3
YJZ8AFJTH 4JI3QPV   Brno        7 16  3
UCEA5JV3O 66NM24PF  Vyskov      8 16  4
F0OPYR    A2IGH     Olomouc     9 24  4
2PPLZ7F   146XPQ6S  Brno       10 25  4
F0ZPB     C8A96T0H  Ostrava    12 33  9
5GAXGL1   FBUE7L    Ostrava    16 13  2
DDV174A0  DG7AP     Ostrava    17  1  1
3R3GO4    4MXRA4C   Brno       18 23  5
UKTS4C9H  91FY4O    Praha      19 22  3
```

Then running the query which is placed higher I got:

```
5GAXGL1   FBUE7L    Ostrava    16 13  2
```

but this tuple is missing, why?

```
F0ZPB     C8A96T0H  Ostrava    12 33  9
```

Comment: sorry, there was mistake by me, now it is correct. It should be t1.city

Comment: please post some sample data, current output and the expected output

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you think you are getting incorrect results?

Comment: Well, I am writing it in java, it will take some time to get output, but for now, I want select all driver's offenses and then select those drivers whose offenses are making point count higher than 7. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Added example to question

Comment: If you want filter before the `count()` use `WHERE`, if you want filter after calculation use `HAVING`

Comment: Would be great if you include column headers

Comment: One suggestion instead of using `t1, t2, t3` as alias is better if you use first letter, that way you have better chances to know what table are you talking about. something like `FROM events e, drivers d, offenses o`

Comment: All tables or just result (name, surname, id, point count, offense count)?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it is automatically generated by SQL Builder which I am using in my project. But I edited question to give it more explaining look...

Comment: `COUNT(e.ID) AS offense_count` => `COUNT(o.ID) AS offense_count`

Comment: I update your question, what are `x, y, z` I add it so you put a real name

Comment: @Hogan It looks, like you have solved my problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: mmm I dont think that is the solution, Can you include your desire result based on your sample table? I mean in the `sum()` can make difference, but not in the `count()`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It really did, now both tuples are included in result, not only the one I already mentioned in question...

Comment: @Hogan Can you please post your comment as an answer, I would really want to know why it did not work...

Comment: Well then good for you. But shouldnt be different, `COUNT(*)` = `COUNT(ID)` = `COUNT(anotherID)` If no null  are involve.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Well, I really do not know why it now works, maybe Hogan will tell us :)

Comment: I just corrected an error in the change to better names.  My change should not have changed the functionality of the HAVING clause so I guess you had a different problem that you fixed without realizing it.

Comment: I had, that was my mistake, all other was good. I was counting IDs in events table, now, counting IDs in offenses table evrything works :D